# How I can fix "Cannot redeclare" error in PHP?

Tags: php

When the language string is "en" I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getSetting() (previously declared in /Users/manuel/Sites/WebApply/datamanager.php:2) in /Users/manuel/Sites/WebApply/datamanager.php on line 10
```

I have already tried to change the require imports to require_once but without success.

index.php

```
if(!file_exists("mysql.php")){
  header("Location: setup/index.php");
  exit;
}
require_once("datamanager.php");
require_once('assets/languages/lang_'.getSetting("lang").'.php');
```

datamanager.php

```
<?php
function getSetting($setting){
  require_once("mysql.php");
  $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE NAME = :setting");
  $stmt->bindParam(":setting", $setting, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    return $row["VALUE"];
  }
}
function setSetting($setting, $value){
  require_once("mysql.php");
  $stmt = $mysql->prepare("UPDATE settings SET VALUE = :value WHERE NAME = :setting");
  $stmt->bindParam(":setting", $setting, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(":value", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
}
function getRankID($username){
  require_once("mysql.php");
  $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE USERNAME = :user");
  $stmt->bindParam(":user", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    return $row["USERRANK"];
  }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Is that an exact copy of `datamanager.php`? I suspect you have a typo in the real file, and wrote `getSetting` where it should be `setSetting`.

Comment: The error message says the problem is on line 10, but line 10 of the code in the question is just `}`.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but it makes no sense to have `return` in a `while` loop. It will return the first row and never continue the loop. It should be `if` rather than `while`.

Comment: if you want only `en` then why there is a `*` and why are looping it simple write `return $row['language'];`

Comment: I found my mistake. I have include in the english language file the datamanager and this resulted in a error.